# How to run batch file using php?

Tags: php, batch-file, xampp, wamp

how can i execute the batch file in wamp server? on Xampp server i get the proper result but on wamp server, get empty result..

```
$gotIt = array();
$file111 = "C:/ABC/run.bat";
//echo $file; exit;
$kkk =  exec( $file111, $gotIt );
//echo $kkk;
$usr = implode("",$gotIt);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($usr);exit;
```

Comment: Maybe the content got lost in copy-pasting, but what is `$usr = implode("",$gotIt);` supposed to do? Also note that the user that runs your web-server is different from your user so the privileges are probably very different as well.

Comment: on xampp server , i got the full path with proper result and $usr = implode("",$gotIt) gives the username ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you tried this?

```
system("cmd /C X:[PATH_TO_BAT_FILE]", &$output);
```

Where parameter

> /C = Carries out the command specified by the string and then terminates
>
> &$output = Return value

### In your case

```
$gotIt = array();
$file111 = "C:/ABC/run.bat";

/** CMD cant return directly Array, but Text */
$CMDOutput = "";
system("cmd /C \"$file111\"", $CMDOutput);
 
/** Split output as you want (With Token, with preg_match, ...) */
$gotIt = mySplitFunction($CMDOutput);

/** 
 * EX. with explode where first param is a token (delimiter)
 *
 * If $CMDOutput contains "Pietro, terracciano", with this
 * instruction you obtain 
 *     $gotIt = array(
 *         'Pietro', 'Terracciano'
 *     );
 */
$gotIt = explode(',', $CMDOutput);

/** ... */
```

Comment: your latest answer give me error....echo '<pre>'; print_r($CMDOutput); exit; gives me 127 number...

Comment: $gotIt = array();
            $file111 = "C:/abc/run.bat";
            //echo $file; exit;
            $CMDOutput = "";
           system("cmd /C \"$file111\"", $CMDOutput);
           $gotIt = splitfunction($CMDOutput);
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($CMDOutput); exit;

Comment: splitfunction not exists!! You must use a preg_match(..) or str_split(..) or explode(..) . Depends how you want to obtain data array from output string

Comment: @RoshanSankhe perfect =)